# tf extrapolation exception using ros::Time(0)

Tags: ros, geometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the latest transform between two frames. What's wrong with this code?

```
listener.waitForTransform(target_frame, source_frame,      ros::Time(0),ros::Duration(.1));
tf::StampedTransform st;
listener.lookupTransform(target_frame, source_frame, ros::Time(0), st);


terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::ExtrapolationException'
  what():  Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1341794988.800442521 but the latest data is at time 1341794988.782343800, when looking up transform from frame [/openni_rgb_optical_frame] to frame [/base_footprint]
```

EDIT: I got this error while playing back a bag file. When I set the parameter use_sim_time true, the error disappeared. I'm still mystified, though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38222/tf-extrapolation-exception-using-ros::time(0)/) by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can happen if you have all links in your transform tree but they are not overlapping.  This can happen if you have poor connectivity to part of your graph and part of the tree is significantly out of date.

The following test is an example: a->b is from t = 1,2,3  b->c is from 10,11,12 and it throws an extrapolation because there is no common time for which it can operate.

```
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>


TEST(TimeCache, Repeatability)
{
  tf::Transformer tr;
  tf::StampedTransform t;
  t.setIdentity();
  t.child_frame_id_ = 'b';
  t.frame_id_ = 'a';

  t.stamp_ = ros::Time().fromNSec(1);
  tr.setTransform(t);

  t.stamp_ = ros::Time().fromNSec(2);
  tr.setTransform(t);

  t.stamp_ = ros::Time().fromNSec(3);
  tr.setTransform(t);

  t.child_frame_id_ = 'c';
  t.frame_id_ = 'b';

  t.stamp_ = ros::Time().fromNSec(10);
  tr.setTransform(t);

  t.stamp_ = ros::Time().fromNSec(11);
  tr.setTransform(t);

  t.stamp_ = ros::Time().fromNSec(12);
  tr.setTransform(t);


  std::string target = "a";
  std::string dest = "c";

  tr.lookupTransform(target, dest, ros::Time(), t);

}



int main(int argc, char **argv){
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `waitForTransform` call is likely timing out. You can look at the return value of `waitForTransform` to figure out if it stopped blocking because the transform is available, or because it timed out. Using a duration of 0.1 is also quite short.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on 2012-07-10**:
nope, it wasn't timing out. I used a longer duration but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think the `waitForTransform` is timing out, because it's throwing a `tf::ExtrapolationException` instead of returning. I've seen this error a lot (it was introduced in some TF update a few months back). I am not 100% sure what is happening (perhaps @tfoote can enlighten us).

What usually helps is something along those lines (warning, pseudocode):

```
time = ros::Time::now();  // or better msg->header.stamp, if available; never ros::Time(0)
success = false;
while (!success) {
  try {
    listener.waitForTransform(target_frame, source_frame, time, ros::Duration(3.0));
    listener.lookupTransform(target_frame, source_frame, time, st);
    success = true;
  } catch (tf::ExtrapolationException e) {
  }
  sleep(0.1);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2012-10-22**:
What is bad in using `ros::Time(0)` instead?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-23**:
It's been a while since I posted this, so I don't remember exactly. But I remember dimly that `ros::Time(0)` always caused the `waitForTransform()` to throw an exception with the specific transforms I tested with, whereas repeatedly waiting for a fixed time (as shown above) would succeed eventually.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I can't explain why this error can happen from this code and would consider it a bug in my understanding of the API.

What the error message says is that the buffer stores data to xxx.78, but you requested data at the time xxx.80 (i.e. later as in the buffer). This usually happens, when you request data with ros::Time::now(), which just isn't there, yet.

However, you are using 0 as the time, which according to the API docs, should mean to get the latest transform. So, if there is data in the buffer this should always work and you should not be able to get an ExtrapolationException.

Simple question: Are you sure it origins from that piece of code?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on 2012-07-10**:
Yes. The error happens here.